# How to redirect multiple subdomains through gateway server to internal app server with single IP address on different ports for each subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, subdomain, squid

I am having a problem with trying to redirect subdomain url to a Application server that have apps on different ports but a single IP address.

Basically, here are the steps:
Client outside the network types in subdomain sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, sub3.example.com. The DNS server is redirecting the information to a Gateway server, so all subdomains go to single external IP address 194.144.144.144. This is done and it works, it shows the Apache default page. The problem i am struggling is to redirect each subdomain from the Gateway server to the internal App server with single IP address 192.168.0.80 that have 3 apps for each subdomain on different ports.

Locally this works perfectly as i am calling the apps for example: https://192.168.0.80:1000,   https://192.168.0.80:2000,   https://192.168.0.80:3000.

However, I want to redirect each subdomain that the gateway server received to the appropriate port on the single IP address App server, as in sub1.example.com -> https://192.168.0.80:1000,  sub2.example.com - > https://192.168.0.80:2000   and   sub3.example.com -> https://192.168.0.80:3000.

I have tried with bind9, with apache virtuahost but no luck. I think I can try with squid also, however if someone can point something to use with apache or something else on Linux Debian. Is this possible ? As shown on the picture bellow.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0zhr.png)

Comment: Apache virtualhosts should work fine here.  I would focus on the actual problems you're encountering.  This would usually mean to include the relevant configuration in your question.  Product recommendations are off-topic for serverfault.

Comment: It looks like you want to setup reverse proxy on Apache.

Comment: I am trying with the following but no luck:
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLProxyEngine On
ServerName sub2.example.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.80:2000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.80:2000/
</VirtualHost>

I enabled proxy and proxy_http